# function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm learning basics of JS and I wrote this script but it doesn't work as I aspected. It should add or subtract 10 value inside  tag and inside  tag value atribute depending on button click.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Meter</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function f(a)
{
    document.getElementById("prog").value = document.getElementById("prog").value + a;
    var t = parseInt(document.getElementById("prog"),10);
    document.getElementById("prog") = t + a;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form title="Meter">
<button type="button" onClick="f(-10);" >Subtract</button>
<button type="button" onClick="f(10);" >Add</button>
<meter  min="0" max="100" value="50" id="prog">50</meter>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well in Google Chrome i get kind of progress bar that works fine but in Firefox an IE I get only text display of inerr tag value as asspected but function doesn't work as aspected it should change that text inside meter tag.

Comment: t+a, well I didn't knew where more to look for err.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should describe what **doesn't work as I aspected** means.

I think the value *inside* the `<meter>` tag not changing is the problem.

My solution is this, using **innerHTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Meter</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function f(a)
{
    //changing the value
    document.getElementById("prog").value = document.getElementById("prog").value + a;
    //(next two lines) changing the innerHTML, which is the inner HTML of an element.
    var t = parseInt(document.getElementById("prog").innerHTML,10);
    //This makes t+a between 0 and 100.
    document.getElementById("prog").innerHTML = t+a<100?t+a>0?t+a:0:100;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form title="Meter">
<button type="button" onClick="f(-10);" >Subtract</button>
<button type="button" onClick="f(10);" >Add</button>
<meter  min="0" max="100" value="50" id="prog">50</meter>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get/set `.innerHTML` of the element.

```
function f(a)
{
    document.getElementById("prog").value = document.getElementById("prog").value + a;
    var t = parseInt(document.getElementById("prog").innerHTML, 10);
    document.getElementById("prog").innerHTML = t + a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the following

```
var t = parseInt(document.getElementById("prog"),10);
```

to

```
var t = parseInt(document.getElementById("prog").value,10);
```

working version > http://jsfiddle.net/6wJGt/

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the property instead the result of the function.

Comment: Can you write that down ,please?